# Is that a good practise to use Textview as a separator instead of View

Tags: android, android-layout, view, textview, android-view

Is that a good practice to use `TextView` as a separator instead of `View`. If not then why?? In the below image I've used both `TextView`(i.e Line 1) and `View` (i.e Line 2), but it looks same. I referred many websites but still, didn't got any good explanation. Here's the code for `TextView` and `View`

[image]

**TextView**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_below="@+id/line1"/>
```

**View**

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/View"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_below="@+id/line2"/>
```

Comment: no. use View for seperator

Comment: textview is also a view

Comment: Read the question @Divyesh. I've asked, if the answer is no then explain why

Comment: but textview has its own method and customizations whereas View has simple methods. You can check their codes. So i think View is better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go through the code of the TextView class, you will see that it extends View. In other words, everything that the View class has is present in the TextView class plus a bunch of other methods, properties and so on. If you use a TextView as a separator you will add a way more complex object to your layout, than the one you actually need. This will decrease the performance of your application and it is possible to introduce future bugs. Thus, do not use TextView as a separator. This is absolutely suitable for just a View.

Answer (score 1):

As Per the my Knowledge the `View` is simply invented for the special kind of design like `Seperator` , `give Border` to shape. or some create special effect.

But `TextView` is design to write `Text` on it.  So To Create `Divider` or `Seperator` the View is better option.

Answer (score 0):

If your use `TextView` just for a Seperator. It will waste some memory. because `TextView` will assign or `new Objects()` in Init, and `onMeasure()` and `onDraw()` will spend more time . so you just use `View` for a divider.